# For some reason I keep getting this TAG error privated in FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

please help this is very confusing. I cant figure this out. I am a newbie to code. This is firebase and android studios. The Language is Java.

```
package com.ExampleStudios.ExampleProject;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.Snapshot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.Snapshot.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
        myRef.setValue("This is an example?");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            //Here is where the tag 1 tag is


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
               //here is the second one

         });   }
}
```

Comment: try replacing TAG to "TAG"

Comment: TAG means naming the tag on Logs (Display on Logcat). Usually user Declare TAG globally like `private TAG = "YourActivity"` or you can directly change the tag just like I suggested in you("TAG" or  "any_tag_you_want").

Comment: you are likely missing Java basics. Please don;t try to continue development before you pass through some basic Java training, or you will get 100 more such questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare TAG before your onCreate()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
        myRef.setValue("This is an example?");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            //Here is where the tag 1 tag is


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
               //here is the second one

         });   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a String object TAG, or you can just enclose it in "".
Like,

```
 Log.d("TAG", "Value is: " + value);
```